# Query 50000 records in apex class and have processing on it

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch

I need to fetch around 300,000 accounts in my apex rest class and then work with them. I tried using aggregate to reduce the records but aggregate takes up alot of time. As mentioned, it is a rest class and i need to send a response back within 120000ms. I also tried using querylocator, but it did not help. If i have to use batch class, how can i return a list of all ids from batch class to the calling apex class ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Database.Stateful` in your batch to store results in some variable and in finish to processing with Rest.

```
public class SomeBatch implements Database.Batchable<Account>, Database.Stateful {
    public Set<Id> idsToProcess = new Set<Id>();

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Id
                FROM Account
        ]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Object> param2) {
        idsToProcess.add('some ids');
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        // do callout
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi ytiq, thanks for response,
Using a batch class is actually delaying the response to be sent. My main class is waiting for the batch class to finish its execution. As of now, i'm trying to implement the logic using future method.

Comment: you shouldn't use another Apex method to wait for Async to finish

Comment: cos it takes different amount of time to process